# How do I create a component by reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have:

```
import MyComponent from "../somewhere"
```

I can create an instance of it by doing:

```
<MyComponent myprops={myprops} />
```

But can I create one programmatically from `MyComponent` and add props?

---

For example, I have a list of component references:

```
import comp1 from "somewhere"
import comp2 from "somewhere"
import comp3 from "somewhere"

var myComponents = [
    comp1, comp2, comp3
];
```

And now I have to take one of them and put in the view:

```
var randomComponent = myComponents[Math.random() * 3 | 0];

// render
render(){
    return randomComponent; // this doesn't work and certain props have to be added
}
```

Is there a way to avoid doing the following and achieve the same?

```
var myComponents = [
    <comp1 props=... />, <comp2 props=... />, <comp3 props=... />
];
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: @AndrewLi Added some details.

Comment: Can't you just do (make sure `RandomComponent` is capitalized): `<RandomComponent props={foobar} />`

Comment: @AndrewLi Does that actually work? I have never tried that approach.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Should work alright, just make sure the component name is *capitalized* so it isn't treated as a DOM element, but I would check to make sure first.

Comment: @AndrewLi Unfortunately I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: @AndrewLi You can assume it's in the same scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135911/discussion-between-andrew-li-and-derek-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var RandomComponent = myComponents[Math.random() * 3 | 0];

render() {
    return <RandomComponent props={foobar} />;
}
```

The above is demonstrated at the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) where the following is mentioned:

> You cannot use a general expression as the React element type. If you do want to use a general expression to indicate the type of the element, **just assign it to a capitalized variable first**. (emphasis mine)

The reason why the component's name *must* be capitalized is because it will be treated as a built-in component (DOM component) if not. This works because it's just transpiled into this:

```
React.createElement(RandomComponent, { props: foobar });
```

And `RandomComponent` still refers to a random selected component. If `randomComponent` is *not* capitalized, you can just do it without JSX like so:

```
React.createElement(randomComponent, { props: foobar });
```

You just won't be able to do it with JSX because `randomComponent` is lowercase and will incidentally be transpiled into this:

```
React.createElement("randomComponent", { props: foobar });
```

Which is problematic as `"randomComponent"` does not refer to `randomComponent`.

Answer (score 2):

see [Create react component dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234500/create-react-component-dynamically)

```
var component = myComponents[Math.random()*3 |0];
return React.createElement(component, props);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would share. I had a very specific use case for this using imported svg files, but I believe this would work with components as well. I wanted to have a button component that would load different svg icons given a prop type.

```
import LightBulb from '../my-icons/Lightbulb.svg';

const ICON_TYPES = {
  LightBulb: 'LightBulb',
};

const ICON_TYPE_FILES = {
  [ICON_TYPES.LightBulb]: LightBulb,
};

export default function IconButton({iconType}) {
  const IconComponent = ICON_TYPE_FILES[iconType];
  return (
    <Icon>
      <IconComponent />
    </Icon>
   );
};
IconButton.ICON_TYPES = ICON_TYPES
```

Using component:

```
<IconButton
  iconType={IconButton.ICON_TYPES.LightBulb}
/>
```